# R: Client Error: Request URI too long

Tags: r, api, url

An R package that I am using, genderizeR, has a monthly limit of 1000 entries for the free plan. The function is connected to the genderize.io database via API.

So I purchased the commercial plan with a larger monthly limit, and use the API key in R like this:

> genderizeAPI (vector, apikey="my_api_key")

However, I got the following error code:

> Client error: (414) Request-URI Too Long

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: 414 means the URL is too long, so nothing to do with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing this:

```
query <- as.list(x)
names(query) <- paste0("name[", 0:(length(x) - 1), "]")
if (!is.null(apikey)) {
  query <- c(apikey=apikey, query)
}
r <- httr::GET("https://api.genderize.io", 
               query = query, 
               httr::config(ssl_verifypeer=ssl.verifypeer))
```

to build the query to send to the API. It ultimately translates something like:

```
genderizeAPI(c("jan", "maria", "norbert"))
```

into:

```
https://api.genderize.io?name[0]=jan&name[1]=maria&name[2]=norbert
```

Which means that (ultimately) you're passing in too large of a vector into the `genderizeAPI()` call.

The `genderize.io` site [clearly states](https://genderize.io/#multipleusage) that *"The API is limited to a maximum of 10 names per request"*.

Make sure that the vector you pass in is <= 10 elements. Frankly a better API package would have accounted for this and I would be inclined (if I were you) to file a bug report/feature enhancement with the author https://github.com/kalimu/genderizeR/issues.